# ¿Cómo se genera una consulta con fecha actual en MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Cómo genero una consulta a una tabla en la condición del WHERE sea la fecha actual, ahorita tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT NOMBRE_AGENTE, COUNT(COMENTARIO) AS CANTIDAD_COMENTARIOS FROM 
bujic_workspace.comentarios WHERE MONTH(FECHA) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(FECHA) = 
YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY AGENTE;
```

Y esta funcionando, pero selecciona lo que va del mes, requiero de la información del día, algo así como con **WHERE FECHA >= NOW()**

Pense que agregandole DAY() antes del MONTH() y YEAR() funcionaria, pero no

No me funciona con:

- FECHA >= NOW
- FECHA = CURDATE()
- DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%Y...') >=

El campo donde se almacena la fecha es DATETIME

```
CREATE TABLE `comentarios` (
`CREDITO` bigint(25) NOT NULL,
`SUBCREDITO` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
`PRODUCTO` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
`FECHA_PROM` date NOT NULL,
`CR` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
`COMENTARIO` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
`MONTO_PP` double NOT NULL,
`AGENTE` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
`NOMBRE_AGENTE` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
`FECHA` datetime NOT NULL,
`TELEFONO` bigint(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='Tabla de comentarios de Workspace';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece entender que buscas:

```
WHERE DATE(FECHA) >= DATE(NOW())
```

La función `DATE()` trunca la hora, por lo que verás todos los registros del día de hoy desde las `00:00:00` horas.

También funcionaría añadiéndole a tu consulta:

```
 AND DAY(FECHA) = DAY(NOW())
```

Tus otras pruebas no funcionan porque la hora está impidiendo que los criterios de selección de registros se cumplan.

Comment: Sí pense que la hora era el problema, pero... ahora te pregunto con "NOW()" ¿No trae la hora también?

Comment: Sí, pero `DATE(NOW())` se queda únicamente con la fecha